# C# How Can I Convert String Into If Else Conditioning

Tags: c#

I'm creating a validation using C#.

My scenario is this. I have a data on the database table with a column name "ending_balance" with a datatype of int. Example I have a value there with

```
ending_balance = 300
```

Then I have a window form with textbox and button for execution. When I type in the value on the textbox

```
txt_payment = 400;
```

The validation will fire because the ending balance is less than the txt_payment value which is "300"

Here's my query and code.

```
private void btn_payment_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

 // Here's the connection and query for selecting the specific column.


   Data select = new Data();
   select.Connection();
   MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT ending_balance FROM tblsalary_payments WHERE customer_id='"+customer_id+"' ORDER BY id DESC", select.connect);
   MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

 if(dr.HasRows == true){
 dr.Read();

   if(txt_payment.Text < dr["ending_balance"].ToString()){
      MessageBox.Show("The Payment Is Greater Than Ending Balance");
   }
   else{
      ... // Execute Query if the Validation Passed
   }
 }
 dr.Close();
```

My Problem is, I don't know how to validate string to string. That's my error. :( I tried to convert them into bool, int, decimal etc. but I can't still validation my textbox.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where did you try to convert it into `int` or `decimal`? Show here

Comment: You're using a less than comparison when it looks like you should be using greater than.

Comment: Your code must be working when you had converted it to `int`, but because your condition is wrong your validation failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
if(Convert.ToInt32(txt_payment.Text) < dr["ending_balance"]){
      MessageBox.Show("The Payment Is Greater Than Ending Balance");
```

Comment: Sir thank you. I convert the dr[]... part now its working :) God bless! Amen :)

Answer (score 2):

You have numbers in strings that you want to compare so you have to convert those strings to number. You can use int.Parse or double.Parse method depending upon what type you have to convert the string to number.

```
 if(int.Parse(txt_payment.Text) < int.Parse(dr["ending_balance"].ToString())){
      MessageBox.Show("The Payment Is Greater Than Ending Balance");
```

As [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) commented if you have number in database you do not need to convert it string and then to number again.

```
if(int.Parse(txt_payment.Text) < dr["ending_balance"]){
      MessageBox.Show("The Payment Is Greater Than Ending Balance");
```

Comment: If the value in the database is already a number, there shouldn't be any need to convert it to text and parse it. Just cast `dr["ending_balance"]` to an appropriate type. (It should probably be `decimal`...)

Comment: @mark, do you mean condition? if so then keep the condition unchanged

Answer (score 1):

You missed text format validation:

```
 // Ensure that the typed text can be converted to int
 int paymentAmount;
 if (!int.TryParse(txt_payment.Text, out paymentAmount))
 {
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Format");
    return;
 }
```

Then the rest would look like:

```
 if (paymentAmount < Convert.ToInt32(dr["ending_balance"]))
 {
    MessageBox.Show("The Payment Is Greater Than Ending Balance");
 }
```

I presume that it is Win Forms application model. If that's the case
there is an event that is better suited for data entry validation: [Control.Validating](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating(v=vs.110).aspx), try to use it instead of handling mouse click or keyboad events directly.